# Python SQLAlchemy query distinct returns list of lists instead of dict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to setup some data models and query it. I have the following table class

```
class Transactions(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'simulation_data'
    sender_account = db.Column('sender_account', db.BigInteger)
    recipient_account = db.Column('recipient_account', db.String)
    sender_name = db.Column('sender_name', db.String)
    recipient_name = db.Column('recipient_name', db.String)
    date = db.Column('date', db.DateTime)
    text = db.Column('text', db.String)
    amount = db.Column('amount', db.Float)
    currency = db.Column('currency', db.String)
    transaction_type = db.Column('transaction_type', db.String)
    fraud = db.Column('fraud', db.BigInteger)
    swift_bic = db.Column('swift_bic', db.String)
    recipient_country = db.Column('recipient_country', db.String)
    internal_external = db.Column('internal_external', db.String)
    ID = Column('ID', db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
```

I'm trying to get distinct row values for columns `recipient_country` and `internal_external` using the following script

```
data = db.query(
    Transactions.recipient_country,
    Transactions.internal_external).distinct()
```

However, this doesn't retrieve all distinct combinations of these two columns (it neglects values for  `Transactions.internal_external` in this case). Example:

```
 {
"China": "External",
"Croatia": "External",
"Denmark": "Internal",
"England": "External",
"Germany": "External",
"Norway": "External",
"Portugal": "External",
"Sweden": "External",
"Turkey": "External"
}
```

When I try

```
data = db.query(
    Transactions.recipient_country,
    Transactions.internal_external).distinct().all()
```

The correct output is returned, however it comes out as a list of lists, and not a dict. Example:

```
[["China","External"],["Croatia","External"],["Denmark","External"],["Denmark","Internal"],["England","External"],["Germany","External"],["Norway","External"],["Portugal","External"],["Sweden","External"],["Turkey","External"]]
```

I'm trying to reproduce the following SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       [recipient_country], 
       [internal_external]
FROM [somedb].[dbo].[simulation_data];
```

I want it to return the data as a dict instead. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` in a dictionary is always unique, so if the country (China) occurs multiple times - once for external and once for external - then setting the value the second time will overwrite the first value:

```py
result = {}
result['China'] = 'internal'
result['China'] = 'external'
print(result) # { 'China': 'external' }
```

How you should visualise your query more is as a list of objects (or dictionaries), with each object representing one row. Then you can have something like

```py
[dict(country="China", internal="internal"), dict(country="China", internal="external"), ...]
```

Here, `country` and `internal` are the column names. You can also get these from the Query object, using [`query.column_descriptions`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.column_descriptions)
before you execute `.all()`.

---

**EDIT**: You can also store the values in an array:

```py
query = db.query(
    Transactions.recipient_country,
    func.array_agg(Transactions.internal_external.distinct())
).group_by(Transactions.recipient_country)

data = {country: options for country, options in query}
print(data) # { 'China': ['internal', 'external'] }
```

Or you can use `"both"` as an identifier to show that `internal` and `external` are both possible:

```py
query = db.query(
    Transactions.recipient_country,
    Transactions.internal_external
).distinct()

data = {}
for country, option in query:
    if country in data:
        option = 'both'
    data[country] = option
print(data) # { 'China': 'both' }
```

Comment: So if I want `recipient_country` to be the key and  `internal_external` to be the value, I need to specify it somehow?

Comment: If you want `recipient_country` to be the key, then there can be only one value for `internal_external` stored. Or you can define a new value `"both"` that denotes that both are true

Comment: But I guess I can do the following: `"China": ["Internal", "External"`]?

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the SQL server version I'm using doesn't support `array_agg` but I'll figure something out.

Comment: Then, you can use `.distinct()` with a [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples)